# nginx auth_basic is not authenticating

Tags: authentication, nginx, nginx-config

I have a fresh install of nginx with the following server definition

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mysubdomain.mydomain.com;

  auth_basic "Restricted Content";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;                                
    
  location / {                                                                  
    return 200 "Nothing exists here.";                                
   }                                
}
```

My .htpasswd file looks

```
name:$apr1$k5bw........
```

But I don't get authentication requests from my browser, it goes straight to the page "nothing exists here".

I've tried the auth_basic_user_file in the location block, before and after the return. I've tried different permissions/ownership of the .htpasswd file.  I get no errors or anything in log files. It just works no matter what name/password I try. There is nothing in my http parent block.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

It seems that if you have a "return" statement, that just gets processed before any of the authentication stuff.  So if you instead do the typical declaration of a root and index, and then do the try_files $uri $uri/ =404; type of stuff in the location block, then it will do authentication.

So this works as intended.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mysubdomain.mydomain.com;

  auth_basic "Restricted Content";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd; 

  root /path/to/root;
  index index.html;

  location / {                                                                  
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #return 200 "Nothing exists here.";                                
   }
```

Don't know if there is a way to make it work w/ a return statement.